# How to change value in datagridview cell and it changes value in other cells of same row? C#

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have data gridview which contains 4 columns buyingprice,profit,discount,finalsellingprice.
If enter value in profit it adds up in buying price and shows in finalsellingprice. Discount is working fine. 
what im trying to do is, i want to add value in finallselling price and it should calculate profit or discount and should show in respective column.
Can you please check whats wrong with my code what should i do to make it work fine.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            if (row.Cells["finalpriceGV"].Value != null && rg.Match(row.Cells["finalpriceGV"].Value.ToString()).Success)
            {
                float buyingprice = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["buyingpriceGV"].Value.ToString());
                float fp = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["finalpriceGV"].Value.ToString());
                if (fp - buyingprice > 0)
                {
                    row.Cells["profitGV"].Value = null;
                    row.Cells["discountGV"].Value = null;
                    row.Cells["profitGV"].Value = fp - buyingprice;
                }
                else if (fp - buyingprice < 0)
                {
                    row.Cells["profitGV"].Value = null;
                    row.Cells["discountGV"].Value = null;
                    row.Cells["discountGV"].Value = buyingprice - fp;
                }
                row.Cells["finalpriceGV"].Value = fp;
            }
            else
            {
                //fp = finalsellingprice;
            }
            if (row.Cells["profitGV"].Value != null && rg.Match(row.Cells["profitGV"].Value.ToString()).Success)
            {
                float buyingprice = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["buyingpriceGV"].Value.ToString());
                float profit = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["profitGV"].Value.ToString());
                //float amounttoincrease = profit +buyingprice;
                float finalsellingprice = buyingprice + profit;
                float discount;
                if (row.Cells["discountGV"].Value != null && rg.Match(row.Cells["discountGV"].Value.ToString()).Success)
                {
                    discount = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["discountGV"].Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    discount = 0;
                }
                row.Cells["finalpriceGV"].Value = finalsellingprice - discount;



            }
            else
            {
                row.Cells["finalpriceGV"].Value = null;
                row.Cells["discountGV"].Value = null;
                row.Cells["profitGV"].Value = null;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe you should consider using ObjectListview (can also be databound).  This would reduce the amount of code you need as you can focus on managing your data objects, not the control (just refresh it) 
 http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net

Comment: Define a data class, with one property  per column, it would be just a better design. From your verbal description I cannot even see, what columns are entered, what are computed. I looks you you take a value in a cell, you modify it, and save it into this same cell again. This means calling the method several times is dangerous, it makes the same modification again and gain. Imagine your grid is an Excel-Sheet. Each cell is either containing a formula, or (entered) data. Never both.